# Soft delete not working in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I can't manage to successfully delete an item with `Asset::destroy($id)` when soft delete is enabled (with `protected $softDelete = true;` in the model). The item doesn't get deleted, and `deleted_at` is not updated. However if I remove the soft delete line from the model, then the item gets removed from the database. I haven't been able to get soft delete to work, or even to find out the cause of this issue.

This is my Asset model code,

```
<?php

class Asset extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array();

    protected $softDelete = true;   

    public static $rules = array(
            'message' => 'required'
        );

    public static function validate($data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Asset` model class?

Comment: Plz, post your model's code.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo Asset model code posted..

Comment: @DennisBraga Model's code posted..

Comment: Do you have the `$table->softDeletes();` statement in your migration for this table, particularly?

Comment: @DennisBraga Forget to say. It worked for me. If you give it as  a answer, i can accept that.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the `$table->softDeletes();` statement in your migration for this table, particularly?

This is the one you need to make the laravel knows it have to create the `delete_at` field, which indicates you soft deleted it or not! =D

Comment: if I add manually the "deleted_at" field it works anyway? or it's necessary migrate the table?

Comment: I think it might solve the problem... but I'm not sure! Never tried!!

Comment: @Lucabro I tried adding that field manually in mysql and made it TIMESTAMP and nullable but somehow it automatically always got turned into NOT nullable and got a default value filled with 000-000 something .This is why it didn't worked. It works when we create the table using $table->softDeletes() inside migrations